# React hooks can't use setState for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At this line. I added an onChange Attribute to change the textbox state and update it. But it is not working, I have no idea why because I try the same/ similar thing at other project and it is working correctly. Is there a limit on how many hooks I can use? Is it better to setState as an object with multiple parameters instead of multiple hooks?

```js
<input value={textbox} onChange={e => setTextBox(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Below is the full code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const StartPage = () => {

    const [players, SetPlayers] = useState(["jaw", "weihan"])
    const [view, setView] = useState(selection)
    //const [roles, SetRoles] = useState(null)
    const [textbox, setTextBox] = useState("")

    const selection = (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setView(addPlayer)}> Create Game </button>
            <button> Join Game </button>
        </div>
    )


    const addPlayer = (
        <div className="add-player">
            <form>
                <input value={textbox} onChange={e => setTextBox(e.target.value)}></input>
                <button type="submit" > Add more</button>
            </form>
            <ul>
                {players.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )


    return (
        <section id="start-page">
            {view}
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What do you expect the state to store, what was the actual result?

Comment: Also, are you using `selection` before `selection` is defined?

Comment: I expect it to change the textbox value everytime I type anything.

Comment: This is just a side note, not the solution to your question but your code currently re-renders the entire component every time you type a character in your input; you might want to consider splitting your page component into smaller chunks, so that only the relevant parts are re-rendered.

Comment: You shouldn't use `onChange` then. `onChange` only updates when the user blurs the field by clicking away. You should be using the `onKeyPress` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={e =>{
 e.preventDefault()
 setTextBox(e.target.value)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to achieve?

```
const [players, SetPlayers] = useState(['jaw', 'weihan']);
  const [textbox, setTextBox] = useState('');
  const [showPlayersForm, setShowPlayersForm] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    SetPlayers(prevState => [...prevState, textbox]);
    setTextBox('');
  };

  const addPlayer = (
    <div className='add-player'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={textbox} onChange={e => setTextBox(e.target.value)} />
        <button type='submit'> Add more</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        // use key when you loop trough items
        {players.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShowPlayersForm(true)}>Create game</button>
      <button> Join Game </button>
      {showPlayersForm && addPlayer}
    </div>
  );
```